# Load data from Oracle table with case sensitive name into Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have Oracle table with case sensitive name and column names. Normally, I can select data from this table with

```
select * 
from "LocationHistory" 
where "Date" > trunc(sysdate, 'DD')
```

But I can't save this as "query": in Kafka Connector parameter because of double quotes.

Please tell me what should I change in this query in order to load data from this table into Kafka via KafkaConnect.

My KafkaConnect parameters:

```
{
    "name": "kafka-geo-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "JdbcSourceConnector",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:****************",
        "mode": "timestamp",
        "timestamp.column.name": "Date",
        "query": "select * from LocationHistory",
        "validate.non.null": false,
        "topic.prefix": "orageo_"
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What predicate are you trying to use to load your data? You've specified `"mode": "timestamp"` but also `incrementing.column.name` (which would be ignored), and you've also specified your own `WHERE` clause (which Kafka Connect does for you if you're using timestamp based on `timestamp.column.name`).

Comment: (I will answer your question about case-sensitivity too but I think you'll still end up with something that doesn't work unless we establish what it needs to actually do)

Comment: Robin, thanks for the comments. I have corrected my Kafka Сonnect parameters